# Interaction between browser() and ls()

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I am trying to find some information as to what is going on under the hood in the interaction between `browser()` and `ls()` in an R Shiny application.

If I add a `browser()` statement to my code outside of an R Shiny function, e.g.:

```
browser()
output$graph_1 <- renderPlot({...})
```

and then call `ls()` in the console I see all variables defined in my environment, as expected. All well and good.

However, if I call add the `browser()` statement within the R Shiny function, e.g.:

```
output$graph_1 <- renderPlot({
    browser()
    ...
})
```

and then call `ls()` then I only see those variables defined within the function.

My understanding from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ls) of `ls()` is that it should return all the variables in the environment, and the environment in this case is the R Shiny session. But I could not find any mention of how that interacts with a Shiny function (or I am not hitting the right key words on Google).

Does calling `ls()` from inside a Shiny function mean that that function *is* the environment? Or is there something else at play? Is there a way to force a list of all variables from inside a Shiny function?

I am on a mac and running R 4.2.0, R Studio RStudio 2022.02.2+485, and shiny version 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the environment in this case is the R Shiny session

No, that’s a misunderstanding. The “environment” in the case of a function call is the *local environment* of that function. However, your case is slightly different still, because you need to distinguish between a function’s local environment and a function *call*.

Inside a function *call* (which is the situation you’re in), the environment is that surrounding the call, so both your cases should yield the same result for `ls()`. At least that would be the case *usually*. However, Shiny’s reactive utility functions (including the `render*` functions) don’t evaluate their arguments in the standard way. Instead, they use [non-standard evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html), and the argument expression is evaluated in its own local environment.

You will need to walk up the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to see variables defined outside the function. In RStudio you can *normally* use the “Traceback” panel for this purpose, but that doesn’t seem to work with Shiny.

Instead, `parent.env(environment())` will give you the parent environment of that expression, and you can run `ls()` on that:

```
ls(parent.env(environment()))
```

Now you should see the variables defined inside your server function.

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed explanation, I really appreciate it! I believe it all makes sense, but I will dive into the documentation for non-standard evaluation as soon as I can.

However, when I try running `ls(parent.env(environment()))` within the `renderPlot` function in shiny, I only get back `~`, and no other variables (which I know are present, and can call them still, just not see them).

Comment: @FitzKaos Hm. It works for me but the exact evaluation and call hierarchy of Shiny reactives isn’t well-specified, and it’s entirely possible that it changes from version to version. Unfortunately this might mean that your best bet is poking around the parent environments (e.g. looking at `parent.env(parent.env(environment())`, etc.). Generally, the debuggability of Shiny is still something that needs to be improved.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help. I will have a mess around and see what I can find out about my specific case. I appreciate you taking the time to teach me this :)